# How to pass a socket descriptor to another process through shared memory?

Tags: networking, ipc, shared-memory, multiprocessor

How to pass a socket descriptor to another process through shared memory?

I pass the socket handle to control the process (getting there right handle value), then passes the handle of the control to another process which should continue to read from the descriptor (here get -1).

Important note: I'm not trying to write or read from the socket at the same time from different processes. I need to transfer the connection to another process without breaking the connection.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, thanks for your reply. When I pass the handle through shared memory, the process gets simple descriptor number, and for him this number does not exist. I understand correctly? What happens in the case of domain socket? How quickly opens and initializes a socket? Can I initialize the socket each time in the "narrow" place in the program?

Comment: If you try to share a descriptor by using shared memory, the second process sees an integer that, from its point of view, refers to either an invalid descriptor or a valid file descriptor that has nothing to do with the socket you intended. It simply won't work. If you use the method with the special msg over a unix domain socket, the kernel opens a new valid descriptor in the receiver that is a duplicate of the other descriptor (and both descriptors can be used until you close them). I don't know the answers to your other questions

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, thanks, it will help.

Comment: APUE has examples of socket passing, if you're looking for code.